# Rewriting continuous Fourier Transform so it works on discrete input?

Tags: integration, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I've realised that any periodic $f(t)$ with period $2L$ can be rewritten as

$$
f(t)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty[a_n\cos(\frac{\pi{n}}Lt)+b_n\sin(\frac{\pi{n}}Lt)]
$$

where the coefficients are calculated using the following integrals:

$$
\begin{align*}
  a_0&=\frac1{2L}\int_a^{a+2L}f(t)\,dt\\
  a_n&=\frac1L\int_a^{a+2L}f(t)\cos(\frac{\pi{n}}Lt)\,dt\\
  b_n&=\frac1L\int_a^{a+2L}f(t)\sin(\frac{\pi{n}}Lt)\,dt
\end{align*}
$$

I want to come up with new expressions for the coefficients that would work on discrete input sequences such as $v=(1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1)$.

## The Aim

[Here is a demos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tfkziqqfoo) with an example of what I'm aiming for.

I'm aiming to be able to take as inputs the list of values $v$ and the variable $\delta{t}$ which specifies the time/x-distance between the y-values in $v$, and I want to output the coefficients $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$.

---

I just tried converting straight from integrals to summations (based on the fact that $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{\delta{x}\to0}\sum_{x=a}^bf(x)\delta{x}$)

I thought these would work:

$$
\begin{align*}
  a_0&=\frac1{2L}\sum_{t=a}^{a+2L}v_t\delta{t}\\
  a_n&=\frac1L\sum_{t=a}^{a+2L}v_t\cos(\frac{\pi{n}}Lt)\delta{t}\\
  b_n&=\frac1L\sum_{t=a}^{a+2L}v_t\sin(\frac{\pi{n}}Lt)\delta{t}
\end{align*}
$$

Where obviously $v_t$ is the $t^\mathrm{th}$ element of the sequence $v$, $\delta{t}$ is the x-distance/time between each element of the sequence and $2L$ is the period of the sequence.

I tried to use these in demos but it didn't work at all, gave me very messy, chaotic, non-periodic (I think) graphs.

What's the correct way of performing a Fourier transform on a sequence?

My specific application will be taking in a list of samples of audio as the sequence, knowing that the time between each sample is $\frac1{44100}$ seconds, and hopefully finding the Fourier series approximation of that data set.

Comment: I don't know what you are really up to, but hopefully this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I've already read through it loads but parts go over my head and the stuff I do understand isn't helpful.

Comment: Then you should better explain your aim.

Comment: There are : the discrete Fourier transform (vector to vector), the Fourier series (periodic function to sequence), the discrete time Fourier transform (sequence to periodic function), the Fourier transform (function to function) and to unify all this we need the Fourier transform of distributions (convolution functional to convolution functional). Not mentioning the Z and Laplace transform and other analytic functional.

Comment: I've edited in a "goal" section